# How can I troubshoot this Hadoop filesystem installation error?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I'm trying to install Hadoop on a non-Cloudera Ubuntu test image. Everything seems to have been going well until I ran `./bin/start-all.sh`. The name node never comes up so I can't even run a `hadoop fs -ls` to connect to the filesystem.

Here's the namenode log:

```
2011-03-24 11:38:00,256 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 54310
2011-03-24 11:38:00,257 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /usr/local/hadoop-datastore/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1015)

2011-03-24 11:38:00,258 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Brash/192.168.1.5
************************************************************/
```

I've `chmod -R 755` on the root directory and even gone so far as to make sure the directory exists by creating it with `mkdir -p`.

```
hadoop@Brash:/usr/lib/hadoop$ ls -la /usr/local/hadoop-datastore/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 hadoop hadoop 4096 2011-03-24 11:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 hadoop hadoop 4096 2011-03-24 11:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 2011-03-24 11:31 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 2011-03-24 11:41 name
```

Here's my `/conf/hdfs-site.xml`:

```
hadoop@Brash:/usr/lib/hadoop$ cat conf/hdfs-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never have to create the directory yourself. It will create it on its own. Did you forget to format namenode? Delete the existing directory, then reformat the namenode (`bin/hadoop namenode -format`) and try again.

Comment: I had run that at one point, but must have screwed up the order of operations. This seems to have cleared things up. Thank you!